# Php: Archives system like blog

Tags: php, html, date, blogs, archive

On my website, I have a "news" page where the customer can add an unlimited number of news (dates are stored in the DB ( with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )).

For example when the user clicks on July, only news of July will be appear on the page.

For now, I only have this :

```
<?php
    $q = $db->query("SELECT dateNews FROM news GROUP BY dateNews");

    while($data = $q->fetch()){
        $dateMonth= $data['dateNews'];
        echo "<a href='#''><p>".strftime('%B %Y', strtotime($dateMonth))."</span></p></a>";
    }                   
?>
```

[image: =>]

But I want this :

[image: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/848x381q90/905/wDH7bi.png]

My dates are listed correctly, but I do not really know how to solve the problem.

Can someone help me please ?

**EDIT :**

After much research, I found a solution for merge the same months :

```
<?php                   
    $q = $db->query("SELECT YEAR(dateNews) AS YEAR, MONTH(dateNews) AS MONTH, COUNT(*) AS newsCount FROM news GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH");

    while($data = $q->fetch()){
        $dateMonth = $data['MONTH'];
        echo "<a href='#''><p>".utf8_encode(strftime('%B %Y', strtotime($dateMonth)))." (" . $data['newsCount'] . ")</span></p></a>";
    }
?>
```

Months are correctly merged, but now I have another problem that I can't resolve :

[image: https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/813x334q90/540/cks3fp.png]

I really don't know what to do or how to do. Somebody knows something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `dateNews` is the month (which it appears to be), then you've almost got it. You just need to also select the count of each grouping and then display it.

```
<?php
    $q = $db->query("SELECT dateNews, COUNT(*) AS newsCount FROM news GROUP BY dateNews");

    while($data = $q->fetch()){
        $dateMonth= $data['dateNews'];
        echo "<a href='#''><p>".strftime('%B %Y', strtotime($dateMonth))." (" . $data['newsCount'] . ")</span></p></a>";
    }                   
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick Q ! It works very well! But like the images, i'd like to "collapse" months who appears more than once and display, when I click, only months's news I selected. Is that possible ?

Comment: Sure, but that's beyond the scope of this question as written. Possibly even beyond the scope of a site like this. At least without you doing some more work on your own first.